# GREEN BOOK: Is there any sheet music available by Don Shirley?

Tags: history, jazz

Don or Doc Shirley was an afro-american pianist and composer **(Movie: GREEN BOOK)**

I am looking for midi files or written music (especially his interpretation of blue skies:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDFnYOOovp8

Comment: It does seem extremely hard to find any written music by Shirley.  Again, it's hard not to see racial bias in why this talented composer and musical visionary has been all but forgotten in the classical world.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I've found is on MuseScore: what appears to be a [fan transcription of "Happy Talk"](https://www.musicnotes.com/sheet-music/artist/don-shirley-trio) from the movie.

No other works turned up in [searches of WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=don%20shirley&dblist=638&fq=%20%28x0%3Abook-%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Aprintbook%29%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Adigital%29%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Amic%29%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Amss%29%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Alargeprint%29%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Athsis%29%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Abraille%29%29%20%3E%20%20%28x0%3Abook-%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Aprintbook%29%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Adigital%29%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Amic%29%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Amss%29%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Alargeprint%29%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Athsis%29%20OR%20%28x0%3Abook%20x4%3Abraille%29%29%20%3E%20ap%3A%22shirley%2C%20don%20d%22&qt=facet_ap%3A), [JWPepper](https://www.jwpepper.com/sheet-music/search.jsp?keywords=don%20shirley) (a music retailer), or "the internet". I can only suggest the admittedly remote possibility of contacting his estate. [See this article from Time magazine](https://time.com/5527806/green-book-movie-controversy/).

Comment: Huh, the prize isn’t modest. So one possibility is to transcribe his songs and sell them for a nice prize. ;)